# How to install dbvisualiser on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-57-generic x86_64) server

Tags: server, webserver, database, domain-server

I want to get data from h2 database which my server is using. After some googling, I found that DbVisualiser may help to read data from an h2 database `.mv` file but could not find a way to install it on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Download it from the official [DbVisualizer website](https://www.dbvis.com/download/) and install it :

```
wget https://www.dbvis.com/product_download/dbvis-9.2.13/media/dbvis_linux_9_2_13.deb
sudo dpkg -i dbvis_linux_9_2_13.deb
```

The current version is 9.2.13.

Comment: When i run second command found this error
dpkg: error processing archive dbvis-9.2.13/media/dbvis_linux_9_2_13.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dbvis-9.2.13/media/dbvis_linux_9_2_13.deb

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the command, please try again ;)

Comment: @ProgrammingBeginner Did it worked ?

Comment: @hg8 yes this worked, after installing you can run `$ dbvis` to start the aplication.